# How to validate radio button in magento?

Tags: validation, magento, radio-button, magento-1.7

In my custom module I have a form which has radio buttons.

When I click the submit button it does not validate the radio button.

How to validate that using the Magento default validate class.

Thanks

Answer (score 42, accepted):

i got the answer,

use `validate-one-required-by-name` in the class name of the radio button.

Cheers

### Edit:

or

use `validate-one-required` on the last radio/checkbox in the group

Thanks to [Rahul Tripathi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501794/rahul-tripathi)

Comment: To add to it:- use class="validate-one-required" and place it on the last radio/checkbox in the group. Make sure there's a parent div wrapping around the group

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Validation works, but to show error message you can't use any wrappers. Just

```
 <label> and <input>
```