# magento : frontend form validation multiple input radio

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs

How can I make sure with magento form validation that one of the multiple input radio is selected ?

Is there a magento way to achieve that or I should do it using prototype/jquery ?

Comment: Duplicated from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19333539/how-to-validate-radio-button-in-magento

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `validate-one-required-by-name` in the class name of the radio button.

Eg : `<input type='radio' class="validate-one-required-by-name"/>`

**Or**

use `validate-one-required` on the last radio in the group.